# Xcode creating tangled git repositories

Tags: xcode, git

I'm attempting to learn git and Objective C - yes, I know Swift is out there. I'm waiting for the excellent BigNerdRanch to publish a book on the topic. And since I have their other book I think it's good for me.

Anyway, I've been creating projects and checking the box for Xcode 5.1.1 to create git repositories on my Mac. For the last 2 projects what I find is that they are tangled up. What I mean is that when I go to the command line I see multiple Initial Commit's that were NOT done for that project.

If this is fixed in Xcode 6 - I can wait. Just curious why this is happening.

These are stored in Dropbox - could that be related? I'm about to reboot and shut down. Maybe somehow git is still open and pulling in everything?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there. I have a hard time understanding what you are seeing and what you are trying (command wise). Could you add some text dumps of what you see in the commandline, that will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Most of my projects look like this:* 162ceb26cshortenedhash - ZB, 6 weeks ago : Initial Commit

Comment: Then I had something happen where I couldn’t open a project. I went to Time Machine and tried to restore it but something happened. Note there is no initial commit.

* 25b0hash - ZB, 2 days ago : slight fix for minus sign
* 3f30a5ehash - ZB, 2 days ago : Try again
* 6424edhash - ZB, 2 days ago : See comments - weird git things going on

Comment: Then I created a new project with the same name +2 at the end and I got multiple initial commits that don’t belong in this project. 

* hash - ZB, 20 hours ago : Initial Commit
* hash - ZB, 20 hours ago : Through page 120
* hash - ZB, 20 hours ago : Initial Commit
* hash - ZB, 2 days ago : Initial Commit
* hash - ZB, 5 weeks ago : pg 94… with intentional errors
* hash - ZB, 6 weeks ago : Initial Commit

Comment: Wow - sorry about the formatting... I only get 600 characters to add onto my question? Do people start a new question and reference it somehow. Sorry I'm new to SO too. You get the idea though, hopefully - git is not sync'd up with Xcode project boundaries.

Comment: No just update your question with the new stuff. There you can use code formatting etc.